# Could women initiate a sin or guilt offering in Second Temple Judaism?

Tags: sin, gender, judaism, atonement

Here, I am not referring to offerings made in response to childbirth.

Say a woman was coerced into regular but proscribed sexual behavior by her husband, would she be capable of initiating a sin or guilt offering on her own?

This, for a fiction project. I've done a lot of background research, and you'd think this would be an easy question to answer, but I'm struggling. Hence, I turn to you!

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! I'm afraid that your question could be closed for not being in line with the [site guidelines](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Hi agarza. Even having read the guidelines, I'm not sure how my question would run afoul of them. Basically, I'm asking whether a Jewish woman in the Second Temple period could initiate a sin offering on her own, without collaboration on the part of her husband.

Comment: "Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange is for anyone who wants to explore what a Biblical text means (exegesis) using techniques or rules of interpretation (hermeneutics)" - Your question has at its core biblical topics but is lacking in the scriptural reference that you want to have analyzed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll go back to the drawing board!

Comment: Better suited for Judaism SE (miyodaya) for the Moses law rituals

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you will need to bear in mind with respect to this question.

1. Sin offerings were not accepted except for sins of ignorance; and
2. Anyone could bring such an offering.

**Sins of Ignorance**

> <sup>2</sup>Speak unto the children of Israel, saying, **If a soul shall
> sin through ignorance** against any of the commandments of the LORD
> concerning things which ought not to be done, and shall do against any
> of them: <sup>3</sup>If the priest that is anointed do sin according
> to the sin of the people; then let him bring for his sin, which he
> hath sinned, a young bullock without blemish unto the LORD for a sin
> offering. (Leviticus 4:2-3, KJV)

> For **if we sin wilfully** after that we have received the knowledge of
> the truth, there remaineth **no more sacrifice for sins**, (Hebrews 10:26,
> KJV)

**Anyone of the People**

> And if **any one of the common people** sin through ignorance, while
> he doeth somewhat against any of the commandments of the LORD
> concerning things which ought not to be done, and be guilty;
> (Leviticus 4:27, KJV)

The usage of the masculine pronoun here in English follows an *English* grammatical requirement which is not present in the Hebrew; that is to say, the word "he" has no basis in the original text, which uses "one/a" in its place.  This is open to any gender.

Perhaps it should have been translated as:

> And if any one of the common people sin through ignorance, while
> **doing** somewhat against any of the commandments of the LORD concerning things which ought not to be done, and be guilty;
> (Leviticus 4:27)

### Conclusion

Yes, a woman could bring an offering, but no offering was accepted for willful, intentional sins--the sin offerings were established for sins of ignorance which, upon realizing that one had sinned, one was obliged to offer.